# How can i improve my StringArray storing and loading?

Tags: android, arrays, json, sharedpreferences

Actually in my app i'm doing some complex operation by downloading an HTML page code formatting it and retriving some specific data from the page, after it i'm storing all the different data in an String array.

After storing the data in array i'm saving it in sharedPreferences using Json for Array items but i'm not sure if that is the best choice, is there any other operation i can do instead for make it save and load the data faster?

PS: i wouldn't use any database as Room or SQlite.

here is my code for saving and loading data:

```
private void saveDataTasti(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TASTI_SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    editor.putString("tasti list", json);
    editor.apply();

}


private void loadDataTasti() {
    new ArrayList<Item>();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TASTI_SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("tasti list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>() {
    }.getType();
    items = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Comment: So you mean your current solution is slow or what? If you don't want to use database, then serialize and store to `SharedPreference` is your only choice, but it's definitely not the best choice. using database for saving complex array of objects is always recommeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preference stores things internally as Files only. So retrieving data from it will be slow as compared to database . Also the stored data is a json string so it adds additional layer of complexity in terms of performance. Offcourse Using SQlite/Room is the ideal choice and you can easily get boiler plate if you searched it. However since you do not want to use these utilities, If your data which you are getting from server is not changing often then you can implement view level caching on in it.

[View Caching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBeN74Xuk2M)

Comment: Actually i fetch the data once when i initialize the app and only if someone change the data on the server that can heppen once per week i'm going to the Activity where i download all the data and redownload it

Comment: then you can apply view caching . may I know why you are not storing the response through sqlite ?

Comment: idk i was more comfortable by using SharedPrefs for later loading the stored data in RecyclerView

Comment: Do you think it will improve a lot if i will use sqlite instead?

Comment: yes , shared preference stores data in flat file . Database is designed to have fast CRUD on data. Also you can deserialize the json string only once and can store all the objects as row if you use sqlite or room . It will save you the cost of deserialising the object every time you fetch it from shared preference and also you can setup cache which will save your network call. Its a one time effort and it will pay you in long term .  Tutorial on sqlite :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2rL3sAFmI